# TypeError while trying to iterate through a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner trying to build a recommendation system based on the skills that a particular candidate has. I want to iterate through each of the skills and store `1` if the candidate has a particular skill or `0` if not.

```
candidate_skillsDF = candidate_resDF.copy()
candidate_skillsDF['primary_skills'] = candidate_skillsDF['primary_skills'].str.split(',')

for index, row in candidate_skillsDF.iterrows():
    for skill in row['primary_skills']:
        candidate_skillsDF.at[index, 'primary_skills'] = 1

# Filling in the NaN values with 0 to show that a candidate doesn't have that column's skill
# candidates_skillsDF = candidate_skillsDF.fillna(0)

candidate_skillsDF.head()
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [40], in <cell line: 5>()
      3 candidate_skillsDF['primary_skills']
      5 for index, row in candidate_skillsDF.iterrows():
----> 6     for skill in row['primary_skills']:
      7         candidate_skillsDF.at[index, 'primary_skills'] = 1
      9 # Filling in the NaN values with 0 to show that a candidate doesn't have that column's skill
     10 # candidates_skillsDF = candidate_skillsDF.fillna(0)

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

I have already tried to use `range()` and `len()` to iterate through the skills. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: The sample df looks something like this :
df1

Comment: please share a sample of candidate_skillsDF.

Comment: I am unable to edit this question for some reason

Comment: The edit queue might be full? If so, you'll have to wait for the edits in the queue to be reviewed by moderators before you can change it again.

Answer (score 0):

`row['primary_skills']` is always going to be the particular contents of a single cell because you're iterating through rows (i.e., 0, 1, 2, ..., n) but *also* only looking at the `'primary_skills'` column. Currently, it's evident that your `'primary_skills'` column is just a series of individual float numbers. Are you sure this is the column you're trying to iterate through? The code you wrote assumes you can iterate through the contents within an individual cell. A single number is not something you can iterate through.

Comment: the column ```primary_skills``` is not a series of float numbers, its actually a series of strings. I tried to use the delimiter ```','``` to convert them into a list and then iterate through them. I'm trying to edit the question to share a sample of the df but SO is not letting me, for some reason

Comment: Ok, gotcha. But what your error traceback is showing is that you're running into numbers, not strings. I'm going to ignore that for now and just assume you're working with a string formatted to look like a list. Provided your column is a series of "list"-formatted strings (i.e., for a given cell, `"['list_item1', 'list_item2', ..., 'list_itemN']"`), you could import `literal_eval` from `ast` and then run `df['primary_skills'] = df['primary_skills'].apply(literal_eval)` so that pandas recognizes the strings as lists. Then,  you should be able to iterate through those lists of strings.

Comment: I'm happy to chat about this more in a couple hours in a private chat if you open up a chatroom.

Comment: Definitely up for chatting about this. Thank you so much

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really know how to open a chatroom

Comment: Feel free to send me an email :) just check my profile

Answer (score 0):

After

```
for index, row in candidate_skillsDF.iterrows():
```

row['primary_skills'] is a value from column candidate_skillsDF['primary_skills'] at position index, but not an array or list where you can run the next for loop. I would iterate through

```
for skill in row:
```

and then add an if statement to check if that is equal to "particular skill"

```
 for skill in row:
     if skill == particular_skill:
```